# Failed to control LED using android Service

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, bindservice

I'm developing an app to control LED. I want to send `String` value from multiple `Activity` so I'm using Android Service to run Bluetooth connection in background. I don't no how to send value from multiple activity to control LED.

Here's the `BluetoothDataService` class

```
public class BluetoothDataService extends Service {
    final int handlerState = 0;
    Handler bluetoothIn;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private ConnectingThread mConnectingThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private boolean stopThread;
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private static String MAC_ADDRESS="98:D3:31:30:A5:00" ;
    private final IBinder mBinder = (IBinder) new LocalBinder();
    private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
    private String on="";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("BT SERVICE", "SERVICE CREATED");
        stopThread = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags,startId);

        Log.d("BT SERVICE", "SERVICE STARTED");
        bluetoothIn = new Handler()
        {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "handleMessage");
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                    recDataString.append(readMessage);
                   // mConnectedThread.write(on);
                    Log.d("RECORDED", recDataString.toString());
                }
                recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());
                    }
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        checkBTState();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        bluetoothIn.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        stopThread = true;
        if (mConnectedThread != null ) {
            mConnectedThread.closeStreams();
        }
        if (mConnectingThread != null) {
            mConnectingThread.closeSocket();
        }
        Log.d("SERVICE", "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(" TEST", "service ONBIND");
        return mBinder;
    }

    //Checks  Bluetooth is available and turned on /off
    private void checkBTState() {

        if (btAdapter == null) {
            Log.d("BT SERVICE", "BLUETOOTH NOT SUPPORTED BY DEVICE, STOPPING SERVICE");
            stopSelf();
        }  else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d("DEBUG BT", "BT ENABLED! BT ADDRESS : " + btAdapter.getAddress() + " , BT NAME : " + btAdapter.getName());
                try {
                    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC_ADDRESS);
                    Log.d("DEBUG BT", "ATTEMPTING TO CONNECT TO REMOTE DEVICE : " + MAC_ADDRESS);
                    mConnectingThread = new ConnectingThread(device);
                    mConnectingThread.start();
                }   catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG BT", "PROBLEM WITH MAC ADDRESS : " + e.toString());
                    Log.d("BT SEVICE", "ILLEGAL MAC ADDRESS, STOPPING SERVICE");
                    stopSelf();
                }
             }  else {
                Log.d("BT SERVICE", "BLUETOOTH NOT ON, STOPPING SERVICE");
                stopSelf();
            }
        }    
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BluetoothDataService getService() {
            return BluetoothDataService.this;
        }
    }

    // New Class for Connecting Thread
    private class ConnectingThread extends Thread {
       // private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            Log.d("DEBUG BT", "IN CONNECTING THREAD");
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket temp = null;
            Log.d("DEBUG BT", "MAC ADDRESS : " + MAC_ADDRESS);
            Log.d("DEBUG BT", "BT UUID : " + BTMODULEUUID);
            try {
                temp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
                Log.d("DEBUG BT", "SOCKET CREATED : " + temp.toString());
            }   catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("DEBUG BT", "SOCKET CREATION FAILED :" + e.toString());
                Log.d("BT SERVICE", "SOCKET CREATION FAILED, STOPPING SERVICE");
                stopSelf();
            }
            mmSocket = temp;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            Log.d("DEBUG BT", "IN CONNECTING THREAD RUN");
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            try {
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.d("DEBUG BT", "BT SOCKET CONNECTED");
                mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
                mConnectedThread.start();
                Log.d("DEBUG BT", "CONNECTED THREAD STARTED");
                mConnectedThread.write("x");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    Log.d("DEBUG BT", "SOCKET CONNECTION FAILED : " + e.toString());
                    Log.d("BT SERVICE", "SOCKET CONNECTION FAILED, STOPPING SERVICE");
                    mmSocket.close();
                    stopSelf();
                    }
                catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG BT", "SOCKET CLOSING FAILED :" + e2.toString());
                    Log.d("BT SERVICE", "SOCKET CLOSING FAILED, STOPPING SERVICE");
                    stopSelf();

                }
             }  catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d("DEBUG BT", "CONNECTED THREAD START FAILED : " + e.toString());
                Log.d("BT SERVICE", "CONNECTED THREAD START FAILED, STOPPING SERVICE");
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
          public void closeSocket() {
            try {

                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.d("DEBUG BT", e2.toString());
                Log.d("BT SERVICE", "SOCKET CLOSING FAILED, STOPPING SERVICE");
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
    }

    // New Class for Connected Thread
  public  class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        //creation of the connect thread
         public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d("DEBUG BT", "IN CONNECTED THREAD");
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

             try {
            //Create I/O streams for connection
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            }   catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("DEBUG BT", e.toString());
                Log.d("BT SERVICE", "UNABLE TO READ/WRITE, STOPPING SERVICE");
                stopSelf();
            }
            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }
        public void run() {
            Log.d("DEBUG BT", "IN CONNECTED THREAD RUN");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

           // write(on);
            int bytes;

            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true && !stopThread) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d("DEBUG BT PART", "CONNECTED THREAD " + readMessage);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                }   catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG BT", e.toString());
                    Log.d("BT SERVICE", "UNABLE TO READ/WRITE, STOPPING SERVICE");
                    stopSelf();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //write method
        public void write(String input) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.d("DEBUG BT", "UNABLE TO READ/WRITE " + e.toString());
                Log.d("BT SERVICE", "UNABLE TO READ/WRITE, STOPPING SERVICE");
                stopSelf();
            }
        }

        public void closeStreams() {
            try {

                mmInStream.close();
                mmOutStream.close();
              }   catch (IOException e2)
             {
                Log.d("DEBUG BT", e2.toString());
                Log.d("BT SERVICE", "STREAM CLOSING FAILED, STOPPING SERVICE");
                stopSelf();
             }
        }
    }
```

I'm sending value from multiple `Activity` to `BluetoothDataService` class to control LED. In my code I want to send value when user click the button.

MY FIRST ACTIVITY

```
public class SendActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button on;
    private BluetoothDataService bluetoothDataService;
    public boolean isBound = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send);
        on= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnon);
        on.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent intent=new Intent (SendActivity.this,BluetoothDataService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public  void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothDataService.class);
        bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Log.v("BINDING", "BIND");
    }

    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            BluetoothDataService.LocalBinder binder = (BluetoothDataService.LocalBinder) service;
            bluetoothDataService = binder.getService();

            isBound = true;
           // BluetoothDataService.ConnectedThread.write("");
            Log.v("ServiceConnection","ServiceConnection");

        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {

            isBound = false;
            Log.v("ServiceDisConnected","ServiDisceConneted");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           if (isBound)
           {
               Intent intent=new Intent (SendActivity.this,BluetoothDataService.class);
                     intent.putExtra("ON", "#ffffff00");
                      startService(intent);
           }
    }

    @Override
       public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
             if (isBound) {
                 Log.v("ServiceStop","ServiceStop");
              unbindService(connection);
              isBound = false;
        }
    }
```

LOG

```
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
12-22 09:17:21.275 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/BINDING: BIND
12-22 09:17:21.275 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{3fa5e5b5 token=android.os.BinderProxy@49e244a {com.example.btest/com.example.btest.SendActivity}}
12-22 09:17:21.275 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{3fa5e5b5 token=android.os.BinderProxy@49e244a {com.example.btest/com.example.btest.SendActivity}}
12-22 09:17:21.276 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{3fa5e5b5 token=android.os.BinderProxy@49e244a {com.example.btest/com.example.btest.SendActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
12-22 09:17:21.277 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2bdd8e84 I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
12-22 09:17:21.293 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/OpenGLRenderer: initialize DisplayEventReceiver 0x7f82818140
12-22 09:17:21.294 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
12-22 09:17:21.338 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f88b54e80) (w:768 h:768 s:768 f:0x1 u:0x000100)
12-22 09:17:21.341 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-22 09:17:21.348 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{3e674f4d com.example.btest/com.example.btest.SendActivity,ident = 0}
12-22 09:17:21.355 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{3fa5e5b5 token=android.os.BinderProxy@49e244a {com.example.btest/com.example.btest.SendActivity}} with isForward=true
12-22 09:17:21.355 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/FeatureProxyBase: FeatureProxyBase class constructor
12-22 09:17:21.355 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/MultiWindow: MultiWindowProxy constructor.
12-22 09:17:21.356 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/FeatureProxyBase: getService(), serviceName = multiwindow_service_v1
12-22 09:17:21.359 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{3fa5e5b5 token=android.os.BinderProxy@49e244a {com.example.btest/com.example.btest.SendActivity}}
12-22 09:17:21.360 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{3fa5e5b5 token=android.os.BinderProxy@49e244a {com.example.btest/com.example.btest.SendActivity}}
12-22 09:17:21.361 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service: CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1aa9ef13 className=com.example.btest.BluetoothDataService packageName=com.example.btest intent=null}
12-22 09:17:21.361 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/ActivityThread: SVC-CREATE_SERVICE handled : 0 / CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1aa9ef13 className=com.example.btest.BluetoothDataService packageName=com.example.btest intent=null}
12-22 09:17:21.359 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{3e674f4d com.example.btest/com.example.btest.SendActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2bdd8e84 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
12-22 09:17:21.361 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/BT SERVICE: SERVICE CREATED
12-22 09:17:21.362 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.example.btest.BluetoothDataService@1ce4c550, flags=0, startId=1
12-22 09:17:21.362 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/BT SERVICE: SERVICE STARTED
12-22 09:17:21.388 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/BluetoothAdapter: isEnabled
12-22 09:17:21.390 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/BluetoothAdapter: getAddress
12-22 09:17:21.394 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/BluetoothAdapter: getName
12-22 09:17:21.405 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: BT ENABLED! BT ADDRESS : CC:5F:BF:3C:D6:5C , BT NAME : Micromax P701
12-22 09:17:21.405 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: ATTEMPTING TO CONNECT TO REMOTE DEVICE : 98:D3:32:20:42:54
12-22 09:17:21.406 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: IN CONNECTING THREAD
12-22 09:17:21.406 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: MAC ADDRESS : 98:D3:32:20:42:54
12-22 09:17:21.406 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: BT UUID : 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
12-22 09:17:21.411 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/BluetoothDevice: mAddress: 98:D3:32:20:42:54
12-22 09:17:21.419 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: SOCKET CREATED : android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@2d669349
12-22 09:17:21.420 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1aa9ef13 startId=1 args=Intent { cmp=com.example.btest/.BluetoothDataService }}
12-22 09:17:21.421 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/ TEST: service ONBIND
12-22 09:17:21.430 15645-15681/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: IN CONNECTING THREAD RUN
12-22 09:17:21.431 15645-15645/com.example.btest D/ActivityThread: SVC-BIND_SERVICE handled : 0 / BindServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1aa9ef13 intent=Intent { cmp=com.example.btest/.BluetoothDataService }}
12-22 09:17:21.433 15645-15681/com.example.btest D/BluetoothAdapter: cancelDiscovery
12-22 09:17:21.436 15645-15681/com.example.btest D/BluetoothAdapter: 151200846: getState(). Returning 12
12-22 09:17:21.444 15645-15681/com.example.btest W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
12-22 09:17:21.502 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7f82825a00 initialize 0x7f88a40a10
12-22 09:17:21.504 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/ServiceConnection: ServiceConnection
12-22 09:17:21.510 15645-15676/com.example.btest E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
12-22 09:17:21.510 15645-15676/com.example.btest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-22 09:17:21.510 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/MALI: eglCreateContext:206: [MALI] eglCreateContext display 0x7f8885f980, share context 0x0 here.
12-22 09:17:21.535 15645-15676/com.example.btest W/MALI: gles_context_new:222: [MALI]ctx init(phase:7) takes more than 20ms here. Elapse time(us): 20956
12-22 09:17:21.537 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/MALI: gles_context_new:248: Create GLES ctx 0x7f828ef008 successfully
12-22 09:17:21.537 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/MALI: eglCreateContext:543: [MALI] eglCreateContext end. Created context 0x7f828df940 here.
12-22 09:17:21.539 15645-15676/com.example.btest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program atlas...
12-22 09:17:21.540 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getFileDescriptor
12-22 09:17:21.541 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapLen
12-22 09:17:21.542 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapArray
12-22 09:17:21.542 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramBinaryLen
12-22 09:17:21.542 15645-15676/com.example.btest I/OpenGLRenderer: Program binary detail: Binary length is 120912, program map length is 112.
12-22 09:17:21.542 15645-15676/com.example.btest I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor is 42, and path is /dev/ashmemt.
12-22 09:17:21.543 15645-15676/com.example.btest I/OpenGLRenderer: No need to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(42).
12-22 09:17:21.543 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/OpenGLRenderer: TaskManager() 0x7f828b01e8, cpu = 4, thread = 2
12-22 09:17:21.544 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-22 09:17:21.545 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7f88a40a00,api=1)
12-22 09:17:21.547 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
12-22 09:17:21.547 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7f88a40a00)
12-22 09:17:21.586 15645-15656/com.example.btest W/art: Suspending all threads took: 33.517ms
12-22 09:17:21.620 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7f88a40a00,w=976,h=600)
12-22 09:17:21.623 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f82abfb00) (w:976 h:600 s:976 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
12-22 09:17:21.628 15645-15676/com.example.btest W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 8107
12-22 09:17:21.657 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#1810100
12-22 09:17:21.658 15645-15645/com.example.btest V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2bdd8e84 V.E..... R......D 0,0-600,976} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@1c7b6f26 controlFlags=#104
12-22 09:17:21.936 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7f88a40a00,w=976,h=600)
12-22 09:17:21.939 15645-15676/com.example.btest D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f88b55560) (w:976 h:600 s:976 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
12-22 09:17:22.124 15645-15681/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: BT SOCKET CONNECTED
12-22 09:17:22.124 15645-15681/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: IN CONNECTED THREAD
12-22 09:17:22.126 15645-15681/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: CONNECTED THREAD STARTED
12-22 09:17:22.130 15645-15720/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: IN CONNECTED THREAD RUN
12-22 09:17:37.752 15645-15720/com.example.btest D/DEBUG BT: java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
12-22 09:17:37.752 15645-15720/com.example.btest D/BT SERVICE: UNABLE TO READ/WRITE, STOPPING SERVICE
```

Comment: Use broadcast and add a `BroadcastReceiver` in your service.

Comment: How to use Broadcast-Receiver in service to control LED.

Comment: There's a plenty of resource in the internet on how to use a `LocalBroadcastReceiver`